# Installation problems: Linux Java and R not working together

Tags: java, linux, r

I almost tried for 3 days now to install rJava and package FSelector on my Linux machine but couldn't do so.
I searched all the forums and tried some tricks ... but unfortunately couldn't find any solution.
First of all I did try to install rJava in my rkward without any changes , that gave me the following error :

```
configure: error: One or more JNI types differ from the corresponding native type. You may need to use non-standard compiler flags or a different compiler in order to fix this.

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’

* removing ‘/home/uwe/.rkward/library/rJava’

Warnmeldung:

In install.packages(pkgs = c("rJava"), lib = "/home/uwe/.rkward/library", :
Installation des Pakets ‘rJava’ hatte Exit-Status ungleich 0
```

So then I started searching and found a tip. I did run the following;

```
uwe@linux-k2a8:~> sudo R CMD javareconf

Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.7.0_45
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_45/jre
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar
NOTE: Your JVM has a bogus java.library.path system property!
  Trying a heuristic via sun.boot.library.path to find jvm library...
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/i386/client
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/i386/client -ljvm
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/linux
Updating Java configuration in /usr/lib/R
Done.
```

And also did check

```
uwe@linux-k2a8:~> java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

uwe@linux-k2a8:~> sudo /usr/sbin/update-alternatives --config java
There are 4 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).
Selection    Path                                     Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk/bin/java   17147     auto mode
  1            /usr/java/latest/bin/java                 1         manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jdk_Oracle/bin/java              3         manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.5.0-gcj/bin/java       1500      manual mode
  4            /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk/bin/java   17147     manual mode
Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

I absolutely don't know what is wrong with that setup since my Java seems to have JDK and all the other things needed for R.

For your Information here my system:

```
uwe@linux-k2a8:~> uname -rm
3.4.63-2.44-desktop i686

uwe@linux-k2a8:~> cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.4.63-2.44-desktop (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version 4.7.1 20120723 [gcc-4_7-branch revision 189773] (S Linux) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Oct 2 11:18:32 UTC 2013 (d91a619)
```

I would be really thankful for any advise to get rJava (and FSelector) running soon.

**UPDATE LOG FILE:**

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by rJava configure 0.8, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.61.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = linux-k2a8.site
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 3.4.63-2.44-desktop
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Oct 2 11:18:32 UTC 2013 (d91a619)

/usr/bin/uname -p = i686
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = i686
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /home/uwe/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/bin/X11
PATH: /usr/X11R6/bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /opt/kde3/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1616: loading site script /usr/share/site/i686-pc-linux-gnu
| #!/bin/sh
| # Site script for configure. It is resourced via $CONFIG_SITE environment varaible.
| 
| # If user did not specify libdir, guess the correct target:
| # Use lib64 for 64 bit bi-arch targets, keep the default for the rest.
| if test "$libdir" = '${exec_prefix}/lib' ; then
| 
|   ac_config_site_64bit_host=NONE
| 
|   case "$host" in
|   "" )
|       # User did not specify host target.
|       # The native platform i386 is not a bi-arch platform.
|       # There is no need to check for compatible sub-architecture.
|       ac_config_site_64bit_host=NONE
| 
|       ;;
|   *x86_64* | *ppc64* | *s390x* )
|       ac_config_site_64bit_host=YES
|       ;;
|   esac
| 
|   if test "x$ac_config_site_64bit_host" = xYES; then
|       libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib64'
|   fi
| fi
| 
| # If user did not specify libexecdir, set the correct target:
| # Nor FHS nor openSUSE allow prefix/libexec. Let's default to prefix/lib.
| 
| if test "$libexecdir" = '${exec_prefix}/libexec' ; then
|   libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
| fi
| 
| # Continue with the standard behavior of configure defined in AC_SITE_LOAD:
| if test "x$prefix" != xNONE; then
|   ac_site_file1=$prefix/share/config.site
|   ac_site_file2=$prefix/etc/config.site
| else
|   ac_site_file1=$ac_default_prefix/share/config.site
|   ac_site_file2=$ac_default_prefix/etc/config.site
| fi
| for ac_site_file in "$ac_site_file1" "$ac_site_file2"
| do
|   test "x$ac_site_file" = xNONE && continue
|   if test /dev/null != "$ac_site_file" && test -r "$ac_site_file"; then
|       { $as_echo "/usr/share/site/i686-pc-linux-gnu:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: loading site script $ac_site_file" >&5
| $as_echo "/usr/share/site/i686-pc-linux-gnu: loading site script $ac_site_file" >&6;}
|       sed 's/^/| /' "$ac_site_file" >&5
|       . "$ac_site_file" \
|           || { { $as_echo "/usr/share/site/i686-pc-linux-gnu:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: error: in \`$ac_pwd':" >&5
| $as_echo "/usr/share/site/i686-pc-linux-gnu: error: in \`$ac_pwd':" >&2;}
| as_fn_error $? "failed to load site script $ac_site_file
| See \`config.log' for more details" "$LINENO" 5; }
|   fi
| done
configure:1847: checking for gcc
configure:1874: result: gcc -std=gnu99
configure:2112: checking for C compiler version
configure:2119: gcc -std=gnu99 --version >&5
gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.7.1 20120723 [gcc-4_7-branch revision 189773]
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2122: $? = 0
configure:2129: gcc -std=gnu99 -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: i586-suse-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --infodir=/usr/share/info --mandir=/usr/share/man --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,fortran,obj-c++,java,ada --enable-checking=release --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --enable-ssp --disable-libssp --disable-libitm --disable-plugin --with-bugurl=http://bugs.opensuse.org/ --with-pkgversion='SUSE Linux' --disable-libgcj --disable-libmudflap --with-slibdir=/lib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-libstdcxx-allocator=new --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-linker-build-id --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-linux-futex --without-system-libunwind --with-arch-32=i586 --with-tune=generic --build=i586-suse-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.1 20120723 [gcc-4_7-branch revision 189773] (SUSE Linux) 
configure:2132: $? = 0
configure:2139: gcc -std=gnu99 -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2142: $? = 1
configure:2165: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2192: gcc -std=gnu99 -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables   conftest.c  >&5
configure:2195: $? = 0
configure:2233: result: a.out
configure:2250: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:2260: ./a.out
configure:2263: $? = 0
configure:2280: result: yes
configure:2287: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:2289: result: no
configure:2292: checking for suffix of executables
configure:2299: gcc -std=gnu99 -o conftest -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables   conftest.c  >&5
configure:2302: $? = 0
configure:2326: result: 
configure:2332: checking for suffix of object files
configure:2358: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  conftest.c >&5
configure:2361: $? = 0
configure:2384: result: o
configure:2388: checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler
configure:2417: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  conftest.c >&5
configure:2423: $? = 0
configure:2440: result: yes
configure:2445: checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g
configure:2475: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -g  conftest.c >&5
configure:2481: $? = 0
configure:2580: result: yes
configure:2597: checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89
configure:2671: gcc -std=gnu99  -c -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  conftest.c >&5
configure:2677: $? = 0
configure:2700: result: none needed
configure:2728: checking how to run the C preprocessor
configure:2768: gcc -std=gnu99 -E  conftest.c
configure:2774: $? = 0
configure:2805: gcc -std=gnu99 -E  conftest.c
conftest.c:8:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
configure:2811: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "rJava"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "rjava"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.8"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "rJava 0.8"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "Simon.Urbanek@r-project.org"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
configure:2844: result: gcc -std=gnu99 -E
configure:2873: gcc -std=gnu99 -E  conftest.c
configure:2879: $? = 0
configure:2910: gcc -std=gnu99 -E  conftest.c
conftest.c:8:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
configure:2916: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "rJava"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "rjava"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.8"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "rJava 0.8"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "Simon.Urbanek@r-project.org"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
configure:2954: checking for grep that handles long lines and -e
configure:3028: result: /usr/bin/grep
configure:3033: checking for egrep
configure:3111: result: /usr/bin/grep -E
configure:3116: checking for ANSI C header files
configure:3146: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  conftest.c >&5
configure:3152: $? = 0
configure:3251: gcc -std=gnu99 -o conftest -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables   conftest.c  >&5
configure:3254: $? = 0
configure:3260: ./conftest
configure:3263: $? = 0
configure:3280: result: yes
configure:3290: checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible
configure:3326: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  conftest.c >&5
configure:3332: $? = 0
configure:3347: result: yes
configure:3371: checking for sys/types.h
configure:3392: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  conftest.c >&5
configure:3398: $? = 0
configure:3414: result: yes
configure:3371: checking for sys/stat.h
configure:3392: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  conftest.c >&5
configure:3398: $? = 0
configure:3414: result: yes
configure:3371: checking for stdlib.h
configure:3392: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  conftest.c >&5
configure:3398: $? = 0
configure:3414: result: yes
configure:3371: checking for string.h
configure:3392: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  conftest.c >&5
configure:3398: $? = 0
configure:3414: result: yes
configure:3371: checking for memory.h
configure:3392: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  conftest.c >&5
configure:3398: $? = 0
configure:3414: result: yes
configure:3371: checking for strings.h
configure:3392: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  conftest.c >&5
configure:3398: $? = 0
configure:3414: result: yes
configure:3371: checking for inttypes.h
configure:3392: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  conftest.c >&5
configure:3398: $? = 0
configure:3414: result: yes
configure:3371: checking for stdint.h
configure:3392: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  conftest.c >&5
configure:3398: $? = 0
configure:3414: result: yes
configure:3371: checking for unistd.h
configure:3392: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  conftest.c >&5
configure:3398: $? = 0
configure:3414: result: yes
configure:3433: checking for string.h
configure:3439: result: yes
configure:3443: checking sys/time.h usability
configure:3460: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  conftest.c >&5
configure:3466: $? = 0
configure:3480: result: yes
configure:3484: checking sys/time.h presence
configure:3499: gcc -std=gnu99 -E  conftest.c
configure:3505: $? = 0
configure:3519: result: yes
configure:3552: checking for sys/time.h
configure:3560: result: yes
configure:3433: checking for unistd.h
configure:3439: result: yes
configure:3575: checking for an ANSI C-conforming const
configure:3650: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  conftest.c >&5
conftest.c: In function 'main':
conftest.c:51:10: warning: 't' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
conftest.c:73:13: warning: 'cs[0]' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
configure:3656: $? = 0
configure:3671: result: yes
configure:3681: checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included
configure:3711: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  conftest.c >&5
configure:3717: $? = 0
configure:3732: result: yes
configure:3743: checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 supports static inline...
configure:3761: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  conftest.c >&5
conftest.c:3:8: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'f' [enabled by default]
configure:3767: $? = 0
configure:3781: result: yes
configure:3792: checking whether setjmp.h is POSIX.1 compatible
configure:3820: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  conftest.c >&5
configure:3826: $? = 0
configure:3841: result: yes
configure:3843: checking whether sigsetjmp is declared
configure:3873: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  conftest.c >&5
configure:3879: $? = 0
configure:3894: result: yes
configure:3910: checking whether siglongjmp is declared
configure:3940: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  conftest.c >&5
configure:3946: $? = 0
configure:3961: result: yes
configure:3993: checking Java support in R
configure:4030: result: present:
interpreter : '/usr/bin/java'
archiver    : '/usr/bin/jar'
compiler    : '/usr/bin/javac'
header prep.: '/usr/bin/javah'
cpp flags   : '-I/usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/../include/linux'
java libs   : '-L/usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/i386/client -ljvm'
configure:4090: checking whether JNI programs can be compiled
configure:4108: gcc -std=gnu99 -o conftest -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -I/usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/../include/linux   conftest.c  -L/usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/i386/client -ljvm >&5
conftest.c: In function 'main':
conftest.c:4:13: warning: unused variable 'o' [-Wunused-variable]
configure:4114: $? = 0
configure:4120: result: yes
configure:4142: checking JNI data types
configure:4167: gcc -std=gnu99 -o conftest -fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -I/usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/../include/linux   conftest.c  -L/usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/i386/client -ljvm >&5
configure:4170: $? = 0
configure:4176: ./conftest
./conftest: error while loading shared libraries: libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
configure:4179: $? = 127
configure: program exited with status 127
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "rJava"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "rjava"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.8"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "rJava 0.8"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "Simon.Urbanek@r-project.org"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_WAIT_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TIME_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME 1
| #define HAVE_STATIC_INLINE 1
| #define HAVE_DECL_SIGSETJMP 1
| #define HAVE_DECL_SIGLONGJMP 1
| #define HAVE_POSIX_SETJMP 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #include <jni.h>
| int main(void) {
|   return (sizeof(int)==sizeof(jint) && sizeof(long)==sizeof(long) && sizeof(jbyte)==sizeof(char) && sizeof(jshort)==sizeof(short) && sizeof(jfloat)==sizeof(float) && sizeof(jdouble)==sizeof(double))?0:1;
| }
| 
configure:4189: error: One or more JNI types differ from the corresponding native type. You may need to use non-standard compiler flags or a different compiler in order to fix this.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_c_compiler_gnu=yes
ac_cv_c_const=yes
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_have_decl_siglongjmp=yes
ac_cv_have_decl_sigsetjmp=yes
ac_cv_header_inttypes_h=yes
ac_cv_header_memory_h=yes
ac_cv_header_stdc=yes
ac_cv_header_stdint_h=yes
ac_cv_header_stdlib_h=yes
ac_cv_header_string_h=yes
ac_cv_header_strings_h=yes
ac_cv_header_sys_stat_h=yes
ac_cv_header_sys_time_h=yes
ac_cv_header_sys_types_h=yes
ac_cv_header_sys_wait_h=yes
ac_cv_header_time=yes
ac_cv_header_unistd_h=yes
ac_cv_objext=o
ac_cv_path_EGREP='/usr/bin/grep -E'
ac_cv_path_GREP=/usr/bin/grep
ac_cv_prog_CPP='gcc -std=gnu99 -E'
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC='gcc -std=gnu99'
ac_cv_prog_cc_c89=
ac_cv_prog_cc_g=yes
r_cv_header_setjmp_posix=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

CC='gcc -std=gnu99'
CFLAGS='-fomit-frame-pointer -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -I/usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/../include/linux'
CPP='gcc -std=gnu99 -E'
CPPFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP='/usr/bin/grep -E'
EXEEXT=''
GREP='/usr/bin/grep'
JAVA='/usr/bin/java'
JAVAC='/usr/bin/javac'
JAVAH='/usr/bin/javah'
JAVA_CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/../include/linux'
JAVA_HOME='/usr/java/default'
JAVA_LIBS='-L/usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/i386/client -ljvm'
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=' -L/usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/i386/client -ljvm'
LTLIBOBJS=''
OBJEXT='o'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='Simon.Urbanek@r-project.org'
PACKAGE_NAME='rJava'
PACKAGE_STRING='rJava 0.8'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='rjava'
PACKAGE_VERSION='0.8'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
R_HOME='/usr/lib/R'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
WANT_JRI_FALSE=''
WANT_JRI_TRUE=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc -std=gnu99'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host_alias=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
subdirs=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define PACKAGE_NAME "rJava"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "rjava"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.8"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "rJava 0.8"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "Simon.Urbanek@r-project.org"
#define STDC_HEADERS 1
#define HAVE_SYS_WAIT_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
#define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
#define HAVE_STRING_H 1
#define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
#define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
#define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
#define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
#define HAVE_STRING_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_TIME_H 1
#define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
#define TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME 1
#define HAVE_STATIC_INLINE 1
#define HAVE_DECL_SIGSETJMP 1
#define HAVE_DECL_SIGLONGJMP 1
#define HAVE_POSIX_SETJMP 1

configure: exit 1
```

Comment: Is it possible that you downloaded a 64-bit library and run a 32-bit java version? Or vice versa?

Comment: no its jre-7u45-linux-i586.tar.gz and jdk-7u45-linux-i586.tar.gz so both 32bit which fits my system. The package i guess delivers both. So there are no different packages for 32bit and 64 bit

Comment: for further information i included the log file in my initial posting

Comment: really nobody here any idea??? :(

Comment: I'm running into the same error message: "checking JNI data types... configure: error: One or more JNI types differ from the corresponding native type. You may need to use non-standard compiler flags or a different compiler in order to fix this." seems like R and Java don't mix that well. Still struggling for a solution..